# Qual è il significato di "sordo" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto questa frase che descrive la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi:

> Imperterrita, come una giocatrice, prepara la nuova tavolazza, mostra come s'impieghi il nero di seppia acciò non sia *sordo*, morde sul pennello un pelo dispettoso: che impasto, che sprezzo, che colorito!

Capisco i significati dell'aggettivo "sordo" che appaiono nei dizionari, ma non riesco a cogliere il senso di questo aggettivo nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nella pittura si chiama "colore sordo" un colore che manca di brillantezza, tipico delle mezzetinte. Il nero di seppia, se veniva preparato in modo sbagliato, risulta smorto e perde le qualità e riflessi brunastri che lo fanno un particolare tipo di nero.

Comment: Vedo che nel [Dizionario della lingua italiana arricchito di tutte le giunte che si trovano negli altri dizionari pubblicati o in corso di stampa e di un copioso numero di voci nuove](https://books.google.es/books?id=UDZTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2406&lpg=PA2406&dq=%22colore+sordo%22&source=bl&ots=MIu0gslmV0&sig=0IuUFGIu9Xd3bXHTzoBVLAXCGpI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj95bGX0O3KAhWLORQKHUm9AbYQ6AEIETAC#v=onepage&q=%22colore%20sordo%22&f=true), pubblicato nel 1839, appare questa definizione di *colore sordo*: "quello che non ha lustro, e fa un tono dolce e vago".

Comment: Sì. Non è riferito alla chiarezza del colore quanto piuttosto all'opacità. Niente splendore. Un esempio classico per acquerelli lo hai diluendo un bruno con più acqua o con latte, tutti e due i modi ti danno un colore più chiaro ma con il latte il bruno diventa appunto "sordo", opaco. Btw il nero di seppia (che è un bruno-nero alla fine) era conservato in polvere, c'è poi tutto un processo di preparazione per arrivare al colore vero e proprio.

Answer (score 1):

In questo contesto *sordo*, normalmente riferito al suono, potrebbe essere impiegato come sinonimo di *cupo* (v. [2 b](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/sordo.shtml)). Il nero di seppia, quindi, verrebbe disteso sulla tavolozza affinché non appaia troppo *cupo*; quanto viene aggiunto dopo, *«che impasto, che sprezzo, che colorito»* lascia intendere che il risultato finale è un'opera dai colori "sprezzanti" (~ "vivaci"), come desiderato.

Comment: Cioè, affinché il colore non sia troppo scuro?

Comment: @Charo Io l'ho intesa così.